# Perserving TestSecurityContextHolder during pure binary websocket connection in Spring Boot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I have an spring boot (1.5.2.RELEASE) app that is using binary websocket (i.e. NO Stomp, AMQP  pure binary buffer). In my test I am able to send messages back and forth which works just great.

However I am experiencing the following unexplained behaviour related to TestSecurityContexHolder during the websocket calls to the application.

The TestSecurityContextHolder has a context that is begin set correctly i.e. my customer @WithMockCustomUser is setting it and I can validate that when putting a breankpoint in the beginning of the test. I.e.

```
public class WithMockCustomUserSecurityContextFactory implements WithSecurityContextFactory<WithMockCustomUser>,
```

That works great and I am able to test server side methods that implement method level security such as

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public UserInterface get(String userName) {
…
}
```

The problem I have starting experiencing is when I want to do a full integration test of the app i.e. within the test i crate my own WebSocket connection to the app, using only java specific annotations i.e. (no spring annotaions in the client).

```
ClientWebsocketEndpoint clientWebsocketEndpoint = new ClientWebsocketEndpoint(uri);
```

.

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class ClientWebsocketEndpoint {


    private javax.websocket.Session session = null;

    private ClientBinaryMessageHandler binaryMessageHandler;
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new  ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public ClientWebsocketEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    ….
}
```

If try calling the websocket then I first see that the “SecurityContextPersistenceFilter” is removing the current SecurityContex which is fully expected. I actually want it to get remove since I want to test authentication anyway, since authentication is part of the websocket communication and not part of the http call in my case, but what bothers me is the following. 
So far we had only  one HTTP call (wireshark proves that) and the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter has cleared the session only once and by setting a breakpoint on the clear method i see that indeed it has been called only once.  After 6 binary messaged (i.e. the SecurityContext is set in the 5 message received from the client) are being exchanged between the client and the server I do authentication with a custom token and write that token to the  TestSecurityContextHolder  btw SecurityContexHolder i.e.

```
        SecurityContext realContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext(); 
        SecurityContext testContext = TestSecurityContextHolder.getContext();

            token.setAuthenticated(true);

            realContext.setAuthentication(token);
            testContext.setAuthentication(token);
```

I see that the hashCode of that token is the same in bought ContexHolders  which means that this is the same object.  However next time I received a ByteBuffer from the client, the result of SecuriyContextHolder.getAuthentication() is null. I first though that his is related  to the SecurityContextChannelInterceptor  since i read a good article about websockets and spring i.e. [here](https://robertleggett.wordpress.com/2015/05/27/websockets-with-spring-spring-security/) but this does not seems to be the case. The securityContextChannelInterceptor is not executed or called anywhere at least when putting breakpoints i see that IDE is not stopping there. Please note that I am deliberately not extending the AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer here since i do not need it i.e. this is plain simple binary websocket with no (STOMP AMQP etc. i.e. no known messaging ). However i see another class i.e. WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener clearing the context

```
TestSecurityContextHolder.clearContext() line: 67   
WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TestContext) line: 143 
TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(Object, Method, Throwable) line: 319 
RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate() line: 94
```

but only when the test finished!!! i.e. that is way after the SecurityContext is null, although manually set with customer token before. It seems that something like a filter (but for websockets i.e. not HTTP) is clearing the securityContext on each WsFrame received. I have no idea what that is.  Also what might be also relative is: on the server side when i see the stack trace i can observe that StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter is being called which is creating the  StandardWebSocketSession.

```
StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$4.onMessage(Object) line: 84    
WsFrameServer(WsFrameBase).sendMessageBinary(ByteBuffer, boolean) line: 592
```

In the StandardWebSocketSession i see that there is a field  "Principal user". Well who is supposed to set that principal i.e. i do not see any set methods there the only way to set it is is during the "AbstractStandardUpgradeStrategy" i.e. in the first call but then what to do once the session it established? i.e. the rfc6455 defined the

*10.5.  WebSocket Client Authentication
   This protocol doesn't prescribe any particular way that servers can
   authenticate clients during the WebSocket handshake.  The WebSocket
   server can use any client authentication mechanism available*

for me that means that i SHOULD be able to define the user Principal in the later stage whenever i want.

here is how to test is runned

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners={ // ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
                                    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
                                    TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
                                    WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class 
                                    }
        )
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
                            SecurityWebApplicationInitializerDevelopment.class, 
                            SecurityConfigDevelopment.class, 
                            TomcatEmbededDevelopmentProfile.class, 
                            Internationalization.class, 
                            MVCConfigDevelopment.class,
                            PersistenceConfigDevelopment.class
} )

@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(SConfigurationProfiles.DEVELOPMENT_PROFILE)
@ComponentScan({
    "org.Server.*", 
    "org.Server.config.*", 
    "org.Server.config.persistence.*", 
    "org.Server.core.*",
    "org.Server.logic.**",

})


@WithMockCustomUser
public class workingWebSocketButNonWorkingAuthentication { 
....
```

here is the before part

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    System.out.println("Starting Setup");

    mvc = MockMvcBuilders
             .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
             .apply(springSecurity())
             .build();

    mockHttpSession = new MockHttpSession(webApplicationContext.getServletContext(), UUID.randomUUID().toString());

}
```

And in order to summarize my question is what could be causing the behaviour where Security Context  returned from the bought TestSecurityContextHolder or SecurityContextHolder  is null after another ByteBuffer (WsFrame) is being received from the client?.

@Added 31 May:
I found by coincidence when running the test mulitple times that  sometimes the contex is not null and the test OK i.e. sometimes the contex is indeed filled with the token i supplied. I guess this has something to do with the fact that the Spring Security Authentication is bound to a ThreadLocal, will need further digging.

@Added 6 June 2017:
I can confirm know that the problem is in the threads i.e.the authentication is successful but when jumping between http-nio-8081-exec-4 to nio-8081-exec-5 the Security Contex is beeing lost and that is in the case where i have set the SecurityContextHolder Strategy to MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL. Any sugesstions are greatly appreciated.

Added 07 June 2017
If i add the SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor does not propagate the security Context in case of the simple websocket.

```
@Bean
@GlobalChannelInterceptor(patterns = {"*"})
public ChannelInterceptor securityContextPropagationInterceptor()
{
    return new SecurityContextPropagationChannelInterceptor();
}
```

Added 12 June 2017
did the test with the Async notation i.e. the one found here. [spring-security-async-principal-propagation](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-async-principal-propagation) . That is showing that the Security Context is being transferred correctly between methods that are executed in different threads within spring, but for some reason the same thing does not work for Tomcat threads i.e http-nio-8081-exec-4 , http-nio-8081-exec-5 , http-nio-8081-exec-6 , http-nio-8081-exec-7 etc. I have the feeling that his has something to do with the executor but so far i do not know how to change that.

Added 13 June 2017

I have found by printing the current threads and the Security Contex that the very first thread i.e. http-nio-8081-exec-1 does have the security context populated as expected i.e. per mode MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL, however all further threads i.e http-nio-8081-exec-2, http-nio-8081-exec-3 do not. Now the question is: Is that expected? I have found here [working with threads in Spring](http://www.ogrigas.eu/spring/2010/04/inherit-spring-security-context-in-child-threads) the statement that

*you cannot share security context among sibling threads (e.g. in a thread pool). This method only works for child threads that are spawned by a thread that already contains a populated SecurityContext.*

which basically explains it, however since in Java there is no way to find out the parent of the thread , I guess the question is who is creating the Thread http-nio-8081-exec-2 , is that the dispatcher servlet or is that tomcat somehow magically deciding  now i will create a new thread. I am asking that because i see that sometimes parts of the code are executed in the same thread or in different depending on the run.

Added 14 June 2017

Since i do not want to put all in one i have created a separated question that deals with the problem of finding the answer how to propagate the security context to all sibling threads created by the tomcat in case of a spring boot app. found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537723/how-to-run-delegatingsecuritycontextrunnable-every-time-when-tomcat-creates-new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the problem, but it's unlikely that the Java dispatcher servlet will create a new thread without being told to. I think tomcat handles each request in a different thread, so that might be why the threads are being created. You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401992/does-tomcat-create-a-thread-per-user) 
 and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776332/how-does-tomcat-create-threads-internally) out. Best of luck!

Comment: thanks for the feedback. It does seems like the tomcat is creating those threads. I am currently searching for the right way to make sure that the Security Context stays in sync between the Threads i.e. make sure that the Object (Security Context) stays in sync between those threads I am not sure what exactlly to use ReentrantLock CountDownLatch, Semaphore, Monitor, do you know if there is anything that spring is advising already?

Comment: I'm not really sure depending on what the situation is, I think ReentrantLock would be your best bet. Synchronized might even work.

Comment: Since spring has DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable but i do not know how to use that in order to wrap the tomcat thread  the target is to synchronize the SecurityContex between sibling threads so i guess i will go with ReentrantLock unless i found the answer how to do that with DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable

Comment: have you used DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable to do something like that before?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't. But it seems really interesting! Maybe you can start a separate question about that.

Comment: I already did  yesturday here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537723/how-to-run-delegatingsecuritycontextrunnable-every-time-when-tomcat-creates-new